# Filtering a layer by an extracted feature?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, select-by-attribute

I am currently getting quite frustrated writing the base of a longer script. What I would like to do currently is to extract an attribute from one layer and select rows in another layer based on an expression which compares the first attribute' value with values in the second layer. Afterwards, I would like to select the rows and go from there.

The main issue now is that it appears as if the expression does accept the column in the second layer, but not the value of the attribute from the first layer with which it is supposed to filter.

So far I checked that both the column and the variable are encoded as UTF-8 as well as a variety of combinations in the expression. The selection works if I exchange the variable (gw) with a value, but this is not what I need.

I found some suggestions that this may not be possible generally, but I would love to hear whether this is actually the case and/or whether there exists a workaround.

Regarding the code, the if statement is only used to avoid going through all rows every time I test it.

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()

epr=layers[0]
ged1=layers[1]
for g in epr.getFeatures():
    gw = g['gwid']
    if gw<436:
        print(gw)
        expr=' "gwno" = "gw" '
        selection = ged1.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expr))
        ged1.setSelectedFeatures([s.id() for s in selection])
        x=ged1.selectedFeatureCount()
        print(x)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
expr=' "gwno" = "gw" '
```

means that you are looking for a value, stored in the `"gwno"` field, which is equal to the `"gw"` string.

I think this is not what you want to achieve. Instead, you probably want to search for a specific value, stored in the `"gwno"` field, for evaluating if it is equal to another value. For doing this, you should rewrite the expression in this way:

```
expr=' "gwno" = %s ' %(gw)
```

The `%s` acts as a placeholder for a string and it is used for formatting strings.